# How to import a mysql database made with mysql workbench into django?

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-workbench, django-mysql

I created a database with MYSQL Workbench 8.0 and I want to import it into Django, so that I can display the data on the browser.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please refer to tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use inspectdb to create the models from the database. I haven't ever done this myself so I can't help you with it, but here's more information about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/